# Django Test Case

Tags: python, django

I am learning how to use Django Test Infrastructure. Very often, it is hard to come up with a good test case.

Here is one test case in Tango with Django tutorial.

```
class CategoryMethodTests(TestCase):

    def test_ensure_views_are_positive(self):

        """
        ensure_views_are_positive should results True for categories where views are zero or positive
        """
        cat = Category(name='test',views=-1, likes=0)
        cat.save()
        self.assertEqual((cat.views >= 0), True)
```

Here is the Category class in models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid1)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs) #python MRO

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I added this line into save method

```
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.slug = slugify(self.name)
       if self.views >=0:
           super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs) #python MRO
```

The test case still fails. There are two questions:
1. How to make the test case pass;
2. How to handle the else case (self.views < 0)?

**Thank Alasdair for the quick answer.**

Follow-up:
I am testing the home page called "Index" views. Here are the test code:

```
class IndexViewTests(TestCase):
    def test_index_view_with_no_categories(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('index'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['categories'], [])



   def **add_category**(name, views, likes):
        c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
        c.views = views
        c.likes = likes
        c.save()

    def test_index_view_with_categories(self):
        add_category('test', 1, 1)
        add_category('temp', 1, 1)
        add_category('tmp', 1, 1)
        add_category('tmp test temp', 1, 1)

        response = self.client.get(reverse('index'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertContains(response, "tmp test temp")

        num_cats = len(response.context['categories'])
        self.assertEqual(num_cats, 4)
```

When I run the test case, it fails:

**add_category('test', 1, 1)
NameError: name 'add_category' is not defined**

The add_category is defined in the class IndexViewTests. How shall this error be fixed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've changed the `save()` method so that the object is only saved to the database if the views is greater than or equal to zero.

However, the test is checking the value of the object, it doesn't matter whether the object is saved to the database or not.

To make the test pass, I would try check the number of views in the save method. If it is less than zero, then change it to another number (e.g. zero). Finally, call the `save()` method outside of the if statement.

Comment: Thanks, I have a follow-up on this since it is the same test file.

Comment: It's better not to mark an answer as accepted if you still have a question, otherwise no-one will see it. It would also be better to ask a separate question but I'll answer quickly this time. The tutorial says that `add_categegory` should be a function in the test file, it shouldn't be a method of the view class. If it was a method then it would be `def add_category(self, name, ...)` and you would call it with `self.add_category('test', ...)`. If you're not familiar with that, it would be a good idea to do some beginner Python tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately this is older but the right answer was never displayed (annoying for those who just want a proper answer)  This tutorial/book series has had a few things that can go sideways due to outdated instructions (like the twitter boostrap versions - have fun with that).. this is just for the save() method

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.views < 0:
            self.views = 0
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```